# How to unterstand "children" in SciLab?

Tags: plot, scilab, graphic

```
clc
 x = [1:1:10];
 y1 = x;
 y2 = 2*x;
 y3 = 3*x;
 plot2d(x,y1);
 plot2d(x,y2);
 plot2d(x,y3)


gca().children(1).children(1).thickness = 2
gca().children(2).children(1).thickness = 7
gca().children(3).children(1).thickness = 4
```

I am new from Matlab to Scilab

Could someone tell me, how to unterstand children?

What means

`gca().children`  ?

`gca().children.children` ?

`gca().children.children(1)` ?

`gca().children(1).children` ?

How can we know which attribute belong to children ?

`e.g gca().children(1).children(1).color = ... // not exist`

I am very confused now.. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's schematize the nested graphical object by their children properties.

We have

```
figure (f)
- axes (a)
  - compound1 (c1)
    - polyline (p1)
  - compound2 (c2)
    - polyline (p2)
  - compound3 (c3)
    - polyline (p3)
```

Since gca is a function lets do `a = gca()` because `gca().children` will raise an error because scilab doesn't understand that you're trying to access to the fields of its return value.

1. `gca()` returns the handles to the axes of the current figure :`a`.
2. `a.children` returns the array of handles of all the children of theses axes. : `c1, c2, c3`
3. `a.children.children` returns the array of handles of all the children of the above objects: `p1, p2, p3`
4. `a.children.children(1)` returns the first children of `c1, c2, c3` : `p1`
5. `a.children(1).children` returns all the children of the first children of the current axes (c1). Since there only one : `p1`

To access the value of your entities

Either go for a temp variable :

```
a = gca();
idcolor=a.children(1).children(1).foreground // gives the color of a.c1.p1
```

or use `get`

```
// idcolor is an array , with idcolor(i) the color of pi
idcolor = get(get(get(gca(),'children'),'children'),'foreground')
```

## FYI

`gce()` command returns the handle of the last object created. With plot2d its a compound so we need to get its children.

you could rewrite your program as

```
clc
x = [1:1:10];
y1 = x;
y2 = 2*x;
y3 = 3*x;
plot2d(x,y1);
e1 = get(gce(),'children');
plot2d(x,y2);    
e2 = get(gce(),'children');
plot2d(x,y3)
e3 = get(gce(),'children');
e1.thickness = 2
e2.thickness = 7
e3.thickness = 4
```